# Activity indicator in Status Bar Wont Stop Animating

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiactivityindicatorview

As the title suggests my activity indicator in the status wont stop animating.

Ive done some research on here and not sure what im doing wrong...

In my Apps delegate I have

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{


UIApplication* app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
app.networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
```

In my view controller.m I want to call the activity indicator

```
 NSString *web = @"http://google.com";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:web];
    NSURLRequest *requestUrl = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [toweb loadRequest:requestUrl];

    UIApplication* app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

     app.networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES; <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
```

Now heres the problem im trying to hide it again with:

```
- (void)DidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)toweb{
 [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
 }    

}
```

Any advice appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

looks like your `UIWebViewDelegate` method name is wrong, it should be

```
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
      [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
}
```

not

```
- (void)DidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)toweb{
     [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
}
```

Hence when the `UIWebView` tries to call its delegate method, there is no method declaration so your class is not being notified that the web view has finished loading.

Also make sure you have set your class as the delegate

`toweb.delegate = self`

and in your .h file

`@interface viewcontroller : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>`

Note that in the delegate callback method, the `webView` parameter is a reference to the webview that has finished loading (in this case its the one you've called `toweb`) This is a *different* pointer to the same `UIWebView` object, so it doesn't need to have the same name as your local declaration/handle to the web view

Comment: Brilliant, thats sorted it, thank you for your advice and detailed explanation, plus one for your sir!